# Import Eve, but upon running run.py, says there is no module named eve

Tags: python, mongodb, eve

I have recently begun looking at Eve.

I have read the Eve [install guide](http://python-eve.org/install.html) and imported it successfully.

Then, I tried the [quick start guide](http://python-eve.org/quickstart.html), and made a few changes to the settings.py. When I try running run.py, it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "run.py", line 1, in
<module>     from eve import Eve ImportError: No module named eve
```

This is my code for run.py:

```
from eve import Eve
app = Eve()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

And this is my code for settings.py

```
MONGO_HOST = 'localhost'
MONGO_PORT = 27017

MONGO_DBNAME = 'clownsighting'

RESOURCE_METHODS = ['GET', 'POST', 'DELETE']
ITEM_METHODS = ['GET', 'PATCH', 'PUT', 'DELETE']

schema = {
    'scarinesslevel' : {'type' : 'string'},
    'date' : {'type' : 'date'},
    'address' : { 'type' : 'string' },
    'city' : {'type' : 'string'},
    'state' : {'type' : 'string'},
    'country' : {'type' : 'string'},
    'continent' : {'type' : 'string'}
}

sightings = {
    'additional_lookup' : {
        'url' : 'regex("[\w]+")',
        'field' : 'date'
        },
    'schema' : schema
}

DOMAIN = {'sightings': sightings,}
```

The two files are in the same directory, if that helps.

Comment: _and imported it successfully_ Did you mean to say you _installed_ it successfully?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Eve is not installed (or you are not in the correct virtual environment). A `pip freeze` will tell you which modules are currently installed. If Eve is not listed, try `pip install eve`.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I was not running the command

```
python run.py
```

inside the virtual environment. I have now, and it works.